# ZSH command runs in shell but not in script

Tags: shell-script, zsh

I run this zsh chained command in my terminal:

```
cd /path/to/backups/pod3 && rm -rf ./*(Om[1,-10])
```

This works fine and removes the appropriate directories as expected.

However, when I put that in a script, I get this error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

I did some research and it seems I need to set this in my shell script:

```
setopt extended_glob
```

However, after I add that line at the top of the script, it throws its own error.

```
setopt: command not found
```

So I am not sure what I am doing wrong here and how to fix this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add a she-bang to your script to tell the system the script has to be interpreted by `zsh`, as otherwise it would be interpreted by `sh` instead:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
cd /path/to/backups/pod3 && rm -rf ./*(Om[1,-10])
```

Change `/bin/zsh` to the actual path of the `zsh` executable, or change the whole she-bang line to:

```
#! /usr/bin/env zsh
```

for the path of `zsh` to be looked up in `$PATH` (assuming the `env` command is in `/usr/bin` which is the case on most systems).