# zsh: repeat: command not found when executing zsh script

Tags: shell-script, scripting, zsh

I just wrote a little zsh script named `test.sh` (and also made it executable) but I get the following error after executing `sh test.sh` :

> repeat: command not found

Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh

repeat 5 java test 0 | grep -E '\[DONE\] | \[FAILED\]'
```

If I execute just `repeat 5 java test 0 | grep -E '\[DONE\] | \[FAILED\]'` in a terminal, it works fine.

Additional infos:

I already tried the solution mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306230/zsh-command-runs-in-shell-but-not-in-script) but all in vain.

`which zsh` returns in `/usr/bin/zsh`

Comment: You are running a `zsh` script in `sh`

Comment: Oh my... Am I blind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run the script with `sh test.sh`, you are running it with `sh`, not `zsh`. The shebang line (`#!/usr/bin/zsh`) is ignored when you explicitly call another interpreter (which is what you are doing with `sh`).

So, either make your script executable and run with `/path/to/test.sh` or use `zsh` and run it with `zsh test.sh`.

Comment: (and avoid `.sh` extension for anything that is not written in `sh` syntax as that's misleading)